# How to implement Infinite Scrolling in ASP .Net for DataGrid Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, datagrid

In a site which is developed by ASP .Net with vb.net , I want to display all my 10000 records in a single page but a set limit of data from a database with infinite scrolling option(like Facebook, twitter). I am using Datagrid control for that and i retrieve data from oracle.

When the user scrolls to the bottom of the window, it loads up some more of the records, like the Twitter feed page does it.

What is the best approach to create infinite scroll. Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Endless Scroll plug-in](https://github.com/fredwu/jquery-endless-scroll).

Markup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').endlessScroll({
        inflowPixels: 100, // start scroll 100 pixels from bottom of DIV
        fireDelay: 2000, // delay in milliseconds
        callback: function (p) {
            // AJAX call to server to fetch more 50, 100 or 
            // whatever amount more of data

        } 
    });
});

<div id="container"></div>
```

Code-behind:

```
Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Put logic here to load initial 50, 100 or whatever initial amount of rows

End Sub
```